# Countability in topology

Tags: general-topology

I am looking at the following example: $\mathbb{R}$ is second countable because consider the open intervals $(a,b)$ with rational endpoints. This is countable base for the usual topology on real line $\mathbb{R}$.

How is the above base base (interval) with rational endpoints countable? Isn't it infinite as it will be a subset of a real line?

Comment: Yes, it’s infinite; this is no bar to its being countable. What do you understand the word *countable* to mean?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: For secound countable spaces the axiom requires us to have countable base. That means it must be "finite". I know the set of rationals are countable. But in this case, we also have irrational numbers in our chosen base. So, this would have to make it uncountable

Comment: Absolutely not! Countable does **not** imply finite. There are countably many rationals, so there are countably many ordered pairs of rationals and therefore countably intervals of the form $(p,q)$ with $p,q\in\Bbb Q$. Those intervals are a base for the topology, and there are countably many of them, so they are a countable base, and the topology is therefore second countable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Could you please elaborate. I do understand that countable does not imply finiteness as our example of rationals. But in this case how can you be sure whether a base is countable or not if it is not finite

Comment: Let $A$ = { (a,b) : a,b is rational } . we are saying that $A$ is countable and is a base for $\mathbb{R}$. we are not saying the set (a,b) = { x : a < x < b } is a base for $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: note that $A$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ rather it consists of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @James: I did expand my comment; see if the expansion answers your question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: So, it does not matter whether the interval is uncountable or not. We just want countable "number" of intervals? Am I correct

Comment: @James: Yes, that’s right. The individual sets in the base can be of any cardinality; all that matters is how many of them there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countable simply means in bijection with a subset of $\mathbb N$ (so not necessarily finite!). One can show that the rationals $\mathbb Q$ are countable and that any countable union of countable sets is also countable. How many intervals are in the set $\{ (a,b): a,b \in \mathbb Q, a<b\}$? This will be a subset of $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ which is also countable, and hence is countable itself.